# How do you cancel a comment?

Tags: support

Twice today, I have accidentally clicked “add comment” and unable to find a cancel button, closed the browser tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete a comment you create, there's a little "x" next to an added comment.

Comment: I’ve seen that.  But if clicking Add was an accident, the only remedies are to type something, post it, then delete it?  Or to close the window and lose the history?

Comment: @WGroleau uh, clicking "Add comment" doesn't do anything server side. There's nothing to _be_ undone, unless you submit it

Comment: I understand that.  That’s why I can “undo” it by closing the window.  I just didn’t expect there to be no cancel (as there is on other things).  Insert obligatory reference to the hobgoblin of my little mind.  :-)

Comment: @WGroleau Someone created a [userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184040/176533) for that. :D